# Error:$("#id").datepicker() is not a function jquery in sharepoint 2013 list New form

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

I have a requirement to disable dates(entire week of Thanks giving day) in date picker control.Its a sharepoint date time control.I am facing error :"$("#control id").datepicker() is not a function" in sharepoint 2013 list New Form.

Checked the **jquery library loading once and jquery UI  library loading after Jquery library**.I am not sure why getting this error on page load.

Below are the code images :where  1st image code  disables all the dates excepts dates that comes on "Thursday"[strDay =4] by default.

So My requirement is to disable the week of "Thanks Giving Day" and 2 weeks of "Christmas" day. Hence, below is the 2 image code written on same date picker field where I just need to disable dates (2022/11/24,2022/12/22,"2022/12/29").As ,only these dates are enabled on the  calendar.

Please suggest ways to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Where you have added this code, inside document.ready() function or somewhere else?

Comment: I know you mentioned jQuery library loading once, but can you try using this: `var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j("#control id").datepicker();`

Comment: it is on page load only. I tried :var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j("#control id").datepicker(); but getting the error still.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path-to-your-jquery.js>"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("BodyOnLoad");
  function BodyOnLoad() {
    // use "jQuery" instead of "#"
    // ... jQuery("#control id").datepicker() ...
  }
</script>
```

If you are using Script Editor webpart, put this webpart to the very bottom of your page.